# Error al convertir un String a un objecto Date con formato dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, date

Buen dia;

Estoy tratando de convertir un `String` que contiene la siguiente cadena `2017-11-29`, a un objeto `Date` con el formato `dd/MM/yyyy`, sin embargo arroja un error al intentar hacer el `parse()`.

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-11-29"

```
DateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String f = "2017-11-29";
try {
    Date fechaPeriodo = formateador.parse(f); //El error se genera aqui
    String periodo = formateador.format(fechaPeriodo);
    fechaPeriodo = formateador.parse(periodo);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Cambia `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` a `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: @eyllanesc Tienes toda la razón, cambiando el tipo de formato funciono a la perfección, es meritorio publicar tu comentario como respuesta para aceptarla como la misma.

Comment: Ya lo publique :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que indicar el formato para que se pueda parsear correctamente, en tu caso dado que la entrada es `"2017-11-29"` el formato adecuado debe ser `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.